# Unity How to get position of child in Grid Layout Group

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, coordinates, grid-layout

I have a gameObject(*GameGrid*) with a Grid Layout Group component, its parent is a gameObject(*GameBox*) with a Vertical Layout Group and his parent is (*MainCanvas*) is a Canvas.

- *GameGrid* = Grid Layout Group
- *GameBox* = Vertical Layout Group
- *MainCanvas* = Canvas

I have another gameObject(Item(0/1/2)) its parent is (*keyboard1*) with a Grid Layout Group and its parent is a gameObject(*Keyboard*) with a Canvas.

- *keyboard1* = Grid Layout Group
- *Keyboard* = Canvasalt text

I have a Drag and Drop script that lets me drag *Item(0/1/2)* to one of *GameGrid*'s children and then changes *Item*'s position to the child's position : (Script is on *GameGrid* children) `eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = GetComponent<RectTransform>().position;` (This works fine)

But when I need to get the children's positions from an other script I can't seem to move Item to the right position. It gives me tiny coordinates as well as huge ones.

Why does this work : `eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = GetComponent<RectTransform>().position;` And not `Item.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = child.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position;` ?

I have tried all the solutions that I've found on forums but none of them seem to work for me.

Am I accessing the position badly or am I setting the position badly ? Both ?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but couldn't solve it completely yet.

According to other forums, i noticed that if you call immediately the method, for getting the position via `GetComponent` of `Childs within Parents`(With applied `Vertical or Horizontal Layout Groups` components) by initialization functions, that would be either their parents' positions or unknown ones.

In my opinion you should call it with simple `Timer-Methods`(Wrong action & inaccurate way) or using `late-initialization function(s)`(I did not find any..)  Afterwards **the whole script loaded properly.**